# Strange "Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed" error when I am setting up the Mock

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2, nunit, moq

I'm getting this error from Moq via NUnit, and it doesn't make much in the way of sense to me.

"Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.DeleteItem(.$VB$Local_item)"

"at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
at Moq.Mock.Verify[T](Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression)
at PeekABookEditor.UnitTests.ItemBrowsing.Can_Delete_Item() in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.UnitTests\Tests\ItemBrowsing.vb:line 167"

Very similar code works well in C#, so the error might be minor and syntactical on my part.

Here's my code:

```
    <Test()> _
Public Sub Can_Delete_Item()
    'Arrange: Given a repository containing some item...
    Dim mockRepository = New Mock(Of IItemsRepository)()
    Dim item As New Item With {.ItemID = "24", .Title = "i24"}

    mockRepository.Setup(Function(x) x.Items).Returns(New Item() {item}.AsQueryable())

    'Act ... when the user tries to delete that product
    Dim controller = New ItemsController(mockRepository.Object)
    Dim result = controller.Delete(24)

    'Assert ... then it's deleted, and the user sees a confirmation
    mockRepository.Verify(Sub(x) x.DeleteItem(item))
    result.ShouldBeRedirectionTo(New With {Key .action = "List"})
    Assert.AreEqual(DirectCast(controller.TempData("message"), String), "i24 was deleted")

End Sub
```

The guilty line appears to be "mockRepository.Verify(Sub(x) x.DeleteItem(item))"

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Working C# code isn't the exact same, but here it is:

```
[Test] 
public void Can_Delete_Product() 
{ 
// Arrange: Given a repository containing some product... 
var mockRepository = new Mock<IProductsRepository>(); 
var product = new Product { ProductID = 24, Name = "P24"}; 
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Products).Returns( 
    new[] { product }.AsQueryable() 
); 

// Act: ... when the user tries to delete that product 
var controller = new AdminController(mockRepository.Object); 
var result = controller.Delete(24); 

// Assert: ... then it's deleted, and the user sees a confirmation
mockRepository.Verify(x => x.DeleteProduct(product)); 
result.ShouldBeRedirectionTo(new { action = "Index" }); 
controller.TempData["message"].ShouldEqual("P24 was deleted");
```

}

Comment: Could you show the working C# code?

Comment: Are you able to test that the C# equivalent of the VB code actually works with the ItemsController? Are you sure it's not *actually* showing you a real bug?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, and furthermore, I'm able to delete items in the normal functionality of the program.  It has to do with how I'm calling the verify/setup functions in moq, and it's likely I'm missing some nuance in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your VB test method, you create `Item` with a string `ItemID = "24"`, but you call the `controller.Delete` method with an integer value of `24`.

Check your controller code and see if the type discrepancy results in the item not being identified correctly, so either `DeleteItem` is not called at all, or is called with a different `Item`.

Comment: Okay, that's fixed, a syntactical error.  Items do indeed accept an integer value in ItemID.

I'm still having the same problem though.

Comment: @user961794, I'm not very familiar with VB, but would it matter whether the `Verify` used `Sub(x)` or `Function(x)`?  If its still not returning the expected result, I would try debugging and stepping through the code as the test runs.

Comment: As the lambda expression does not return anything, Function(x) causes a syntax error.